# Alter Table by ExecuteSqlCommand in Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, execute, sqlcommand

I try to alter a table in sqlserver. After editing the default value I execute this query and do not have any problem. The query gets executed correctly. But when I try the same query in *EF* with `ExecuteSqlCommand` I get and error.

The query goes:

```
ALTER TABLE tblPerson
    ADD [ddd] nvarchar(Max)

  ALTER TABLE tblPerson
    DROP COLUMN [dd]

UPDATE tblPerson
SET    aa = '---',
       bb = '---',
       cc = '---',
       ddd = '---',
       Id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001',
       ModifiedDate = '2016/03/13 15:53:24',
       ModifiedUser = 'c012e46c-2a03-4238-917c-659c1ab3f33b'
WHERE  (Id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001')

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0


  INSERT INTO tblPerson
              (aa,
               bb,
               cc,
               ddd,
               Id,
               CreateDate,
               ModifiedDate,
               ModifiedUser)
  VALUES      ('---',
               '---',
               '---',
               '---',
               '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001',
               '2016/03/13 15:53:24',
               '2016/03/13 15:53:24',
               'c012e46c-2a03-4238-917c-659c1ab3f33b');
```

This query runs on the sql console correctly but when I run it like this:

`context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(stringCommand);`

I get this error:

> Invalid column name 'ddd'.

Comment: Is that the full error message? Doesn't it read something like "You have an error in your sql syntax blah on line X?

Comment: the error is Invalid column name 'ddd'.

Comment: I would assume the problem is that when the query gets parsed the table does not have a column ddd and it causes the error. Run the alter + drop statement separately before the update and it should work ok.

Comment: hi JamesZ, you are right, 
if I run the alter + drop statement separately before the update  it works ok,
but i want run query on one transaction.